# How to keep the intermediate data with any High-Order operator?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm using the `switchMap` and `mergeMap` and need to keep some extra data.

See the code

```
    from(fileList)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((file: File) => {
          return this.s3Service.checkExists(file);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((hash: any) => {
         // I want to access to the `file:File` here as well
        console.log(`hash exists`, hash, file);
      });
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the result of your `s3Service.checkExists` method to an object which includes the original file:

```
from(fileList)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((file: File) => {
      return this.s3Service.checkExists(file).pipe(map(hash => ({hash, file})));
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
     // I want to access to the `file:File` here as well
    console.log(`hash exists`, data.hash, data.file);
  });
```